# #define x 2|0 in C

Tags: c, macros, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

The below given code is written to satisfy the condition **(x == x+2)** to be returning true in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define x 2|0

int main()  
{
    printf("%d",x==x+2); 
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code why the `printf()` is printing `2` ( if I write `x+3` I get `3` and so on ).

Can someone explain how the given macro is working.

What is the use of `|` operator in C and what does the macro

```
#define x 2|0
```

mean? I read about macros in other questions but no question explained similar kind of example.

Comment: What does the preprocessed code say?

Comment: `|` is bitwise OR, if that helps.

Comment: Expand the macro. Look at the operators precedence table. Understand. Be enlightened.

Comment: I know you're learning. It's good to learn this stuff... but don't use it for real in the future.

Comment: @pmg why is it so ?

Comment: Macros are replaced with the defined content during compilation. Try it on paper and check what will be compiled. I doubt that "and so on..." is true.

Comment: @VoidLimbo Cryptic and confusing code is good good only for c00L h4xx0r competitions.

Comment: `#define x 1.0e100` will likely also satisfy `x==x+2`

Comment: OP seems to be talking about [this answer to a challenge on CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7166/744).

Comment: @Paul here is where i found it [(x == x+2) make it equal for x - Programming Puzzles](http://www.developerinsider.in/x-x-2-make-it-equal-for-x-programming-puzzles/?utm_campaign=turbocpp)

Comment: @VoidLimbo: yes, it looks like they plagiarised that content from the [CodeGolf challenge that I linked to above](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7165/when-does-x-x2/7166#7166) - they even stole [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7182/744) !

Comment: @PaulR Great minds think alike  (they also think differently).  Perhaps `#define x 0>>1`?

Comment: @chux: you can see it's been plagiarised wholesale because the solutions are copied *verbatim* (even the comments!).

Comment: @paul I thought "stole my answer" was referring the similarity to my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766599/define-x-20-in-c#comment74575187_43766599) and your [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7182/744).

Comment: @chux: oh I see - no, I was referring to the fact that they had stolen numerous answers from the CodeGolf challenge, including mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR;** Read about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

`+` binds higher than `==` which binds higher than `|`.

After preprocessing, your `printf()` statement looks like

```
 printf("%d",2|0==2|0+2);
```

which is the same as

```
 printf("%d",2|(0==2)|(0+2));
```

which is

```
printf("%d",2|0|2);
```

---

***Word of advice:*** Do not write this type of code in real scenario. With minimal level of compiler warning enabled, your code produces

> ```
> source_file.c: In function ‘main’:
> source_file.c:4:12: warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of ‘|’ [-Wparentheses]
>  #define x 2|0
>             ^
> source_file.c:8:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘x’
>      printf("%d\n\n",x==x+2); 
>                      ^
> source_file.c:4:12: warning: suggest parentheses around arithmetic in operand of ‘|’ [-Wparentheses]
>  #define x 2|0
>             ^
> source_file.c:8:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘x’
>      printf("%d\n\n",x==x+2);
> ```

So, the moment you change the MACRO definition to something *sane*, like

```
#define x (2|0)
```

the result will also change, as the explicit precedence then will be guaranteed by the parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you @Sourav i got it now.

Comment: I will keep your advice in mind as well. I don`t use macros that much i was just wondering how it was working. Now i got to know more about macros. Thanks to you @Sourav

Answer (score 1):

After running the preprocessor, `gcc -E main.c` you will get:

```
int main()
{
    printf("%d",2|0==2|0 +2);
    return 0;
}
```

Since `(0==2)` is 0, `2|0|2`